# Can someone construct in ZFC BAs with CSr equal to the following relation?

Tags: set-theory

Can someone construct in ZFC BAs with CSr equal to the following relation?
{(w,w),(w,w1),(w1,w1),(w1,w2)}

Comment: Welcome to MO, nasarp. Should those w's be $\omega$'s? You can use LaTeX as you normally would. To ease readability, you should also consider expanding abbreviations at least once unless they are very standard. (ZFC is ok, BA is not that bad, CSr should be expanded.)

Comment: The algebraic topology tag should be removed.

Comment: @François: please go ahead and expand the abbreviations yourself if you are confident about what the asker means.

Answer (score 1):

The construction of a Boolean Algebra with this sort of subalgebra-cellularity, assuming CH, appears e.g. in Monk, p. 76,

http://books.google.gr/books?id=51PqDepAAUYC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=CSr+boolean&source=bl&ots=pKM8uoye8v&sig=2cHUyj-9yFUX3JUT20A_EY1S3dM&hl=el&ei=MaDkS9GpAYKQsAbrk7CdBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false

Whether this can be done in ZFC alone seems to me an open problem (but I won't take an oath!)

Comment: The particular question of the OP is asked as Problem 5 (i) on page 77 of the linked text. 